# How can i match the css height left and right div?

Tags: html, css

I want to match the left and right div height equally.

This is the code.

html,

```
<div id="base">
            <div id="leftleft">
                left
                <br/>
                I WANT THIS HEIGHT TO BE SAME AS RIGHT DIV
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div id="rightright">
                RIGHT DIV HEIGHT WILL BE
                <br/>
                CHANGED DYNAMICALLY BASED ON THE SERVER SIDE DATA.
                <br/>
                I WANT TO MATCH THE LEFT
                <br/>
                AND RIGHT DIV HEIGHT EQUALLY.
                <br/>
                right
                <br/>
                right
                <br/>
                right
                <br/>
                right
                <br/>
                right
                <br/>
                right
                <br/>
                right
                <br/>
                right
                <br/>

            </div>
        </div>
```

css,

```
    #leftleft {
            float: left;
            background: #1B8BC6;
            width: 300px;
        }
        #rightright {
            float: left;
        }
        #base {
            height: 100%;
        }
```

fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/9Kwry/1/

Can somebody give me advise with this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript?

Comment: what browser does this have to be compatible for? if ie8 and above then you can use display table: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kwry/3/

Comment: yes of course. javascript is allowed

Comment: @Canna JavaScript is not needed for this. Check my answer out, sweet and simple!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can do this `display: table;` then set the `divs` with `display: table-cell`. So the left and right will always be the same. Good old tables!

### CSS:

```
#leftleft {
    background: #1B8BC6;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
#rightright {
    display: table-cell;
}
#base {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kwry/2/)

Answer (score 2):

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/9Kwry/4/)

**CSS**

```
#leftleft {
    display:table-cell;
    background: #1B8BC6;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    }

#rightright {
display:table-cell;
}

#base{
height: 100%;
display:table;
}
```

Comment: Pshhh! Too late! I'm 25 seconds ahead of you! :P

Comment: @Ruddy :) Happens to the best of us.

Comment: I will upvote because it is correct and 25 seconds is next to nothing XD

Comment: Ditto..seems reasonable. :)

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can use **[.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)**:

```
$('#leftleft').height($('#rightright').height());
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kwry/5/)**

Actually, it's better to use pure CSS with `display: table` and `display: table-cell` but if you care about older browser support such as IE7 then jQuery will help you to achieve this task.

Comment: Huh? Who said anything about jQuery?

Comment: I asked him in the question.

Comment: JavaScript, you asked if he could use JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery is javascript.

Comment: Lul! jQuery is not Javascript. You said Javascript so use it. Agreed oGeez (your comment after this one)

Comment: Being able to use JavaScript doesn't automatically mean the jQuery library is available to you though.

Comment: @Canna Ah, we are not arguing. More like discussing :)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery>

```
$(function(){
         var lh=parseFloat($("#leftleft").css("height").replace("px",""));
         var rh=parseFloat($("#rightright").css("height").replace("px",""));
          if(lh>rh){
                $("#rightright").css("height",lh+"px")
              }
           else{
                  $("#leftleft").css("height",rh+"px")
             }
});
```